# Subscribe to Notification Event semilar to Observer pattern

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, wait, observer-pattern

Before I ask my question I want to say, I know there are many semilar question. But they don't really cover my scenario as I want to show in a moment.

I'm facing the following scenario:

There is a `Database` class, which is private to another class Im gonna call `DBMS` (DatabaseManagementSystem),that provides secure read/write access to the DB. And yet another class Im gonna call `Consumer`.

The `DBMS` and the `Consumer` run their own thread. The `DBMS`-thread just takes queued data and writes it to the `Database`. The `Consumer` processes data from the `Database` provided by the `DBMS`.

The classical Producer-Consumer pattern, with a thread-safe queue in between (which is suggest in other questions here) isnt really applicable here, because then I'd need to copy all the data from the `Database` into a thread-safe queue or another thread-safe structure. This doesnt quite comply with the design of a `DBMS` providing safe access to the `DB`. 
Furthermore it is to expenct that most of the time the consumer is going to wait for new changes in the `DB`, and a single consumer will just need a small bit of the data stored in the `DB` so pushing all the data to the consumers would produce lots of unnecessary overhead.

To conclude:

Ideally the `Consumers` would wait for the `DB` to change, then get notified by the `DBMS` and finally read the needed data and process it.

My plan:

I want to implement a kind of observer pattern. So every consumer puts itself into wait state after it finished processing the data, and gets notified by the `DBMS` when the `DB` got changed. A `Consumer` can subscribe to receive a notification event from the `DBMS`.

Now my question is: Is there a pattern that covers this scenario? Or has somebody implemented a semilar design and has some suggestions for me ?

Since this is more a design question I'm not quite sure if this matters, but I'm working with Java (`JDK8`).

Many thanks in advance,
Flo

Comment: Why need "to copy all the data from the Database"? Won't putting only updates into a queue be sufficient?

Comment: Not quite because after a change was made, the changed data might not be the only data the consumer needs.

Comment: Most likely, code for your task will implement several patterns, working together. Seems like more constructive way to go is to write sketch of a code and post it to codereview.SE, or something like that. In short -- start with a code snippet.

Comment: Regarding the consumers getting notified, use [Guava EventBus](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/EventBusExplained) ?

Comment: Consider using the [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava) library, [here](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/what-is-functional-reactive-programming/) is a good explanation.